# Why are most of the classes in package org.apache.hadoop.mapred deprecated?

Tags: hadoop

I am learning Hadoop recently, and I am very curious about why most of the classes in org.apache.hadoop.mapred are deprecated. This is very annoying because the package names and class names used in MapReduce before and after Hadoop 0.20 are very similar, which makes learning Hadoop much more difficult.

However, I think there must be some good reasons for the contributors to do such a decision. Does anyone know the exact reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/05/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-hadoop-core-020/) and [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2010/08/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-apache-hadoop-0-21/) blogs for the rational behind developing the new API and the information on it. Note that the old API has been unappreciated and some of the classes have not been ported from the old API to the new API. Unless there is a specific requirement the old API can be used.